# Using Synology Cloud Station on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, cloud, synology

is there a proper way to use the Synology Cloud Station Client on Debian? There are only Fedora/Ubuntu Versions, and though Ubuntu is based on Debian as far as I know its not that much of a great idea to install Ubuntu Packages on Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Ubuntu package for over 3 months now and there were no complications so I guess its no problem!